# C source code AST parser in Java

Tags: java, c, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm looking for an C source code parser that can create a comprehensive AST from it.

Preferably a Java library (I'd rather not have to use Python here -> http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may well be easiest for you to use ANTLR and get it to generate an AST based on an existing ANTLR grammar, e.g. [the source](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/c/C.g4).

ANTLR has a Java API here: http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/index.html

Comment: You might be able to build a C parser; certainly ANTLR builds fine parsers in the narrow sense.   But what OP wants appears to be something that reads real C programs.   The detail work to get this right is much bigger than you think:  preprocessor, dialects (C89, C99, C11, ...), vendor varients (GCC, MSVC, GreenHills), character sets.     You are better off getting one that already does all this rather than trying to re-invent it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt) project has a C parser written in Java, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300668/396730) to a similar question.

Answer (score -2):

Our [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html) is not in Java, definitely not in Python :-} but provides robust parsers for many real dialects of C code.  It goes beyond building just ASTs; it provides a preprocessor, symbol tables, local and global flow analyses, which you will need if you want to do anything to C other than just "having an AST".

It comes built on top of our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMSToolkit.html), which provides the infrastructure for parsing and flow analysis, can apply transforms to the AST using patterns, and can regenerate valid source code.

EDIT July 2015 (in response to comment): DMS itself is implemented in a parallel programming language, PARLANSE, which is C-like in capability but includes fine-grain parallelism constructs as well as exception handling. DMS provides a set of DSLs for defining language processing:  a fully-Unicode capable lexer, BNF for grammars,  attribute grammars for computing tree-shaped analyses, and source-to-source transformations useful for pattern recognition and rewriting the source code.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson:  What part of  "*looking for a C source code parser*" does this not answer directly? Where's the critique in this answer?

Comment: Looked over the top to me mate. Guy also asked for java, and you didn't say what it was built in.  Built in our .. also made it a tad iffy in my eyes. If it was me I'd have done this as a you might want to look at comment. PS I didn't do the downvote...

Comment: Good work, there's even AS3