# Parsing / reading C-Header files using Java

Tags: java, c, header-files

I have a C-Header file defining a couple of stucts, containing multiple char arrays.

I'd like to parse these files using Java. Is there a library for reading C-Header files either into a structure or is there a stream parser that understands C-Header files?

Just for more background (I'm just looking for a C-Header parser, not a solution for this particular problem):
I have a text file containing data and a C-Header file explaining the structure. Both are a bit dynamic, so I don't want to generate Java class files.

example:

```
#define TYPE1
typedef struct type1
{
char name1[10];
char name2[5];
}
#endif
```

Type2, Type3 etc are similar.

Data structure:

```
type1ffffffffffaaaaa
```

Comment: the man-pages for lex and yacc (flex and bison) may help

Comment: Oh good point, I forgot about yacc. I was hoping there would already be an existing solution for this. But I guess I could create my own streaming parser using yacc.

Comment: @PhilW, have you created your parser? I need to parse C Header containing preprocessor definitions (just integer constants). I need to get these constants from C Header to Java application. Of course I'm looking for some kind of ready-made solution before implementing my own one =)

Comment: Hey Dmitry, unfortunately not - I didn't get around to it and got caught up with other things... But if you find the time, let me know ;-) (I struggled with the CDT thing below for a while, but didn't get it to work, I think I would rather do my own parser)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use an existing C parser for Java. It does a lot more than parsing header files, of course, but that shouldn't hurt you.

We use the parser from the [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt) project. This is an Eclipse plugin, but we sucessfully use it outside of Eclipse, we just have to bundle 3 JAR files of Eclipse with the parser JAR.

To use the CDT parser, start with an implementation of `org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.ILanguage`, for example `org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.gnu.c.GCCLanguage`. You can call `getTranslationUnit` on it, passing the code and some helper stuff. A code file is represented by a `org.eclipse.cdt.core.parser.FileContent` instance (at least in CDT7, this seems to change a lot). The easiest way to create such an object is `FileContent.createForExternalFileLocation(filename)` or `FileContent.create(filename, content)`. This way you don't need to care about the Eclipse `IFile` stuff, which seems to work only within projects and workspaces.

The `IASTTranslationUnit` you get back represents the whole AST of the file. All the nodes therein are instances of `IASTSomething` types, for example `IASTDeclaration` etc. You can implement your own subclass of `org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.ASTVisitor` to iterate through the AST using the visitor pattern. If you need further help, just ask.

The JAR files we use are `org.eclipse.cdt.core.jar`, `org.eclipse.core.resources.jar`, `org.eclipse.equinox.common.jar`, and `org.eclipse.osgi.jar`.

**Edit**: I had found a paper which contains source code snippets for this:
"Using the Eclipse C/C++ Development Tooling as a Robust, Fully Functional, Actively Maintained, Open Source C++ Parser", but it is no longer available online (only as a shortened version).

Comment: Sounds like a good fit! Would you mind throwing in a few keywords or pointers on how to do this? (what are the main classes in this scenario?)

Comment: In fact I do have a question: In my sample above, I have a macro "#define type1" - how do I make my ASTVisitor visit that?

Comment: I'm not sure how it supports pre-processor statements, as our code has none of them. But there are some methods in `IASTTranslationUnit` which seem to give you access to pre-processor statements like `#define`.

Comment: Thanks - I'm actually still struggeling to create a IFile object.. Looks a bit difficult when you're not using it inside a plugin environment. Also, I found that the C-Model, in here (Using CDT APIs to programmatically introspect C/C++ code by Markus Schorn) http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/CDT_APIs_for_code_introspection.pdf might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: I added how we do this. Thanks for the link, I did not know that slides. Every bit of documentation about CDT is welcome, as docs are quite rare (at least we have the source).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found - the docs are also there, but not much how the things work together. Thanks for your update. I also found this http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg17031.html regarding the preprocessor statements. I can get them, but not in a way they would be of any use to me, as I need to know what they encapsule.  I might add more comments here, along the way. Thank you for your help so far!

Comment: You talk about FileContent, which is fine, and you talk about IASTTranslationUnit, but I don't see how the two are related. Once I have a FileContent object, what do I do with it to turn it into the AST? The IASTTranslationUnit and its parent does not seem to have any functions that interact with FileContent.

Comment: @searchengine27 As I wrote, you need the `ILanguage` instance (e.g., `GCCLanguage`). This has the method `getTranslationUnit` which converts `FileContent`s to `IASTTranslationUnit`s.

Comment: I see, I think I misread. Lots of classes mentioned above...CDT is a bit intimidating.

Comment: paper link is 303 Forbidden

Comment: @JasonS Indeed, I removed it as I cannot find it anywhere else.

Comment: For finding research papers, the most reliable source is scholar.google.com. For this paper, https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Alberto_Sillitti/publication/266483397_Using_the_Eclipse_CC_Development_Tooling_as_a_Robust_Fully_Functional_Actively_Maintained_Open_Source_C_Parser/links/550693800cf231de0777fec0.pdf is the link.

Comment: Does is support MSVC developed code?

Answer (score 7):

Example using **Eclipse CDT** with only 2 jars.
- https://github.com/ricardojlrufino/eclipse-cdt-standalone-astparser
*In the example has a class that displays the structure of the source file as a tree and another example making interactions on the api ...*

A detail is that with this api(Eclipse CDT Parser) you can do the **parsing from a string in memory.**

Another example of usage is:
https://github.com/ricardojlrufino/cplus-libparser
*Library for metadata extraction (information about classes, methods, variables) of source code in C / C ++.*

See file:
https://github.com/ricardojlrufino/cplus-libparser/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/criativasoft/cpluslibparser/SourceParser.java

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already, CDT is perfect for this task. But unlike described above I used it from within a plugin and was able to use IFiles. Then everything is so mouch easier. To get the "ITranslationUnit" just do:

```
ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(myIFile);
IASTTranslationUnit ias = tu.getAST();
```

I was i.e. looking for a special #define, so I could just:

```
ppc = ias.getAllPreprocessorStatements();
```

To get all the preprocessed code statements, each statement in array-element. Perfectly easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). There should be already some [existing C grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/list) available for it.