# How to find the number of specific characters in the read file in java

Tags: java

I have to read a c code and analyze the code. For example, the number of functions in the code, such as the number of operators. I tried a lots but  I'm very new in the Java programming language, i didn't happen. I read a lot of topics, tried to do it with the scanner class, but it didn't happen. Can you help me?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{ 
    File file = new File("C:\\main.c"); 
    FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
    InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(fileStream); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input); 

    String line; 




    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    { 

        String[] operatorsNumbers=line.split("+");
        int operators=operatorsNumbers.length;

    } 

    System.out.println("number of operators" + operators );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315205/c-source-code-ast-parser-in-java

Comment: You need a C *parser*.

Comment: it is sufficient to list only the function names and parameters. no need for much detail. i know its simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the .C file here? Also, why are you splitting based on "+"? Is it that your C code contains only the + operator? And what exactly are you trying to achieve from parsing the C code? You want a list of all operators, functions used in the C code?